# Heroku Node js file changes are not saving

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I have simple discord bot with leveling system runing on node.js , all user stats are saving into .json file.

Everything looks fine, but when I'm trying to open file via Heroku's bash cat it's showing me state of file when it was originally pushed.

Also, I'm facing issue when after some time user's stats are being deleted, I'm thinking that because file (some how) being wiped back to original state.

p.s. Updates was pushed via GitHub integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku restarts your app once a day, at this point, the file's contents are also "reset" (means changed to what they were when the repository was initialized), if you want saving files you could try out https://glitch.com instead: Free 24/7 Node.js hosting with 500MB of storage. If you want to stay with Heroku tho, you should use a database instead of files.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku storage isn't persistent which means whatever data you're saving to a file lives until that dyno is shut down or restarted.

You can read more about it here.
https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted